# Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php on line 228 this error coming in loading magento site in localhost. when reloading some part of webwite is coming with the same error. [image]

Comment: Please add more info to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information, i can only recommend increasing the max_execution_time in your php configuration.

Find php.ini and max_execution_time variable and restart PHP.
php.ini should be `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`

Otherwise you can post the error logs here so we can track down the actual error.

Comment: i set max_execution_time=18000, after that also get same issue

Comment: Make sure you restart PHP after a change like that. If it doesn't work, try taking a look at `C:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log`

Comment: [:error] [pid 2336:tid 1716] [client ::1:50065] script 'C:/xampp/htdocs/mabtest/media/index.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://localhost:8080/mabtest/ this error is coming on error.log file.

Answer (score 1):

Set Maxexecution time in your php.ini file
max_execution_time = 18000

To check the maxexecution time is set or not 
create one test.php file

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

http://prntscr.com/hsaco0